# How to enable/disable and change color of some links depending on the selection user have made from a - slect dropdown menu -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

**Hello.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!.**

I have a html file where there is a select dropdown menu with 5 options and just below it there will be a yet not determined number of links.

When user arrive to this page, the dropdown menu will be in it's default option wich is "Choose an option". In this state, all links below should be not clickable and greyed out (disabled).

Then, depending on user's selection from dropdown menu, some of the links below should change its color to blue and should become clickable and some others should remain not clickable and greyed out.

The reason we need this is because links point to resources and not all resources are available for all the options from the dropdown menu.

I have no experience in Javascript / JQuery, so I know how to apply the style but not in a conditionally way.

```css
.select-box {
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 200px;
}

.resource-link {
 border:  solid;
 border-width: 4px;
 border-color: grey;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 75px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>

 <select class="select-box">
  <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option5">Option 5</option>
 </select>

 <ul >
  <a href="resource1.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 1
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource2.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 2
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource3.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 3
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource4.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 4
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource5.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 5
   </div>
  </a>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: "and just below it there will be a yet not determined number of links"? Makes a HUGE difference in complexity of the solution.

Comment: <a href="resource2.html" disabled='disabled'> for all the anchor tags

Comment: You need to fix your HTML. an `a` can't be a direct child of a `ul`. you need to wrap the `a`'s in `li`'s

Comment: @MichaelCoker It can be. It won't be ordered. Thats all.

Comment: @jonmrich It is going to be a fixed number of links at the biginning, but we will be adding some more links  (manually) in the future. These links will not be generated dynamically.

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt "it can be" as in it's possible, but it's invalid HTML. That's my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `pointer-events` of the links to `none` by default (so they are disabled), then monitor the `change` event of the select to trigger an `.active` class on the links' parent elements and conditionally change `pointer-events` and `color` and whatever else you want with the selected option from the select list.

I've reduced your example down to 2 items because you have broken HTML. You need to add `li`'s to wrap the `a` links in your `ul`.

```js
var selectBox = document.getElementById('select-box'),
    lis = document.getElementById('options-list').getElementsByTagName('li');

selectBox.addEventListener('change',function() {
  var val = this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if (lis[i].classList.contains(val)) {
      lis[i].classList.add('active');
    } else {
      lis[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.select-box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
}

.options-list a {
  border: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  text-decoration: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.active a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select class="select-box" id="select-box">
  <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
 </select>

<ul class="options-list" id="options-list">
  <li class="Option1">
    <a href="resource1.html">
      <div class="resource-link">
        Link to Resource 1
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="Option2">
    <a href="resource2.html">
      <div class="resource-link">
        Link to Resource 2
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="Option2">
    <a href="resource2-1.html">
      <div class="resource-link">
        Another Link to Resource 2
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, one last question. Will this work if i need to active more than one link for each selected option?

Comment: @Rigel no worries. Sure, updated my answer. You would just give all of the elements you want associated with a particular value in the select list the same class in the li's

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery and do something like this:

```
$('.select-box').on('change', function() {
    $('.link').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('.link.' + $(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Then on each of your links put the appropriate classes like so:

```
<a href="whatever" class="link option1" disabled>whatever</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the disabled attribute for all the anchor tags and then remove the attribute based on your dropdown selection

```
<a href="resource1.html" id="res1">
                <div class="resource-link">
                    Link to Resource 1
                </div>
            </a>

    $('.select-box').change(function(){
    $('#res1,#res2...').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this

```
$("select.select-box").change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).val();

    switch (selected) {
        case "Option1":
            //enable the link you want 
            $("ul li a").first()
                .removeAttr("disabled")   // enable the link 
                .addClass('active');      // style it 
        case "Option2":
            .....
        case "Option3":
             .....
       case "Option4":
             .....
       case "Option5":
            .....

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing font-weight, but you can adjust code as you wish. It's not clear for me what exactly you want. You didn't provide any desired styles, that should be applied to selected item.

```js
var smart, that;

smart = document.querySelector('.select-box');
that = document.querySelectorAll('ul a');
//console.log(that);
smart.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var enough;
  
  enough = smart.value;
  enough = enough.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  enough = Number(enough);
  
  Array.prototype.filter.call(that, function(thoughts) {
    return thoughts.style.fontWeight === 'bold';
  }).forEach(function(here) {
    here.style.fontWeight = '';
  });
  
  Array.prototype.filter.call(that, function(sea) {
    return new RegExp(enough + '\\.html').test(sea.href);
  }).forEach(function(sea) {
    sea.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  });
})
```

```css
.select-box {
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 18px;
 height: 35px;
 width: 200px;
}

.resource-link {
 border:  solid;
 border-width: 4px;
 border-color: grey;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: grey;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 margin-right: 75px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>

 <select class="select-box">
  <option value="choose">Choose an option</option>
  <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="Option5">Option 5</option>
 </select>

 <ul >
  <a href="resource1.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 1
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource2.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 2
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource3.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 3
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource4.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 4
   </div>
  </a>
  <a href="resource5.html">
   <div class="resource-link">
    Link to Resource 5
   </div>
  </a>
 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```